# js excel addin charts.add method issue

Tags: office365, office-js, excel-addins, javascript-api-for-office

some time ago(unfortunately I can not say how long exactly) I start to get an issue with the charts function - here is an example from script lab which exactly reproduces what I have in my project: when I create a chart by button from the tagline (chart 2) everything is alright, but when I try to create a chart by call charts.add function from js code I get a kind of "empty diagram" (chart 1)(it can be fixed by press column/row button from the tagline, but it is not appropriate solution for me). it happens just for a diagram with a two-column range and just in the web version of excel, but unfortunately, all my diagrams have a two-column range and the web version is the main point of my add-in. Please help me find out any appropriate solution that I can implement and use from the code and help me understand if it is a bug in js add-in API.

[image]

Comment: Can you share your code? i tried with the script lab sample, it works well in my side.

Comment: repro steps for scriptLab
1. open script lab and find "create charts" example
2. press the "create table" button in the scriptLab menu
3. remove all columns from the table but the first two
(table shall look like on my screen)
4. press the "create a line chart" button in the script lab menu
(here u will get a chart like the chart with number 2) 
5. then select the range of table (A1:B7) and add a chat by the classic way - insert -> linear diagram 
(at this moment you will get a situation like on my screenshot)
5.1 - also try to press "switch row/column" for one of the charts.

Comment: I just give it a try, seems both 2 charts look like your chart 2. the only difference are Chart Title, value numbers, legend were added via scriptlab code.

Comment: well, then I still need your help, because I still have the problem and it is not my local problem, because it had been reported to me by the customer. maybe I was not clear enough in my repo steps for you. sorry for that, so here is my demonstration   https://recordit.co/XPHxzm6Qqe

Comment: I can repro this issue now, it seems only repro on Excel online, it works expected on Windows and Mac, would you please report this issue on https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues

Answer (score 0):

I also tried and cannot repro the issue, so can you ensure clear local js cache and have a try? Also please try other browser you don't use before.

Comment: unfortunately, it always reproduces in edge, chrome, and opera // http://g.recordit.co/XPHxzm6Qqe.gif -example from chrome